# Starting MediaPlayer from another class

Tags: java, android

How can I start a MediaPlayer from a class that is not a Activity? I need a reference to my MainActivity

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create([WhatToPutHere], R.raw.cpiano);
    mp.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create media player as `public static`, and by using class name with media player object you can start your media player where ever you want, Either in Java class or in an Activity.

Comment: What do you mean with using class name with media player?

Comment: When you use public static variable or object outside the class then you need to give the class name like MainActivity.mp.start();

Comment: and what do i have to put in [WhatToPutHere]?

Comment: Then it says "there is no sich reference available here"

Comment: public static MediaPlayer mp; do it globally, and mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cpiano); inside onCreate();

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can. This is an example:

```
class mMP {
        private Context _context;
        private _resId;
        public mMP(Context context,int resId){
            this._context=context;
            this._resId=resId;
        }
        public void playSong(){
            MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create(_context, _resId);
            if(mp!=null)
                mp.start();
        }
    }
```

then call this from Activity, Service or BroadcastReceiver:

```
new mMP(this,id).playSong();
```

or make static void like :

```
 class yourClass{public static void playMusic(Context c,int resId){MediaPlayermp=MediaPlayer.create(c,resId);if(mp!=null) mp.start()}}
```

then call your function from Activity, ... `yourClass.playMusic(this,resId);`

Comment: But i do not want to call it from an activity. I need to call it from an object

Answer (score 0):

It's referenced to an activity, so you can in Activity class:

```
public static Activity activity;
```

then in your class you can get that activity:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ActivityClassName.activity, R.);
mediaPlayer.start();
```